# html5 navigator.geolocation.getcurrentposition() returns 0,0

Tags: javascript, html, web, geolocation, navigator

I recently made a web app and part of it looks for the user's location.

```
function complete(pos) {


    var coordinates = pos.coords;

    var positions = {lat: coordinates.latitude, lng: 
    coordinates.longitude};
    console.log(positions);
}
 function fail(error) {
    console.log('failed')
};

var opt = {
    enableHighAccuracy: true
};
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(complete, fail, opt)
```

But, in some locations like my school, it always returns (0,0) for some reason. It works perfectly fine in other locations, like on private networks.
Can anyone suggest any reasons why or any workaround? Thanks. (I already white listed the site I was using to run this and allowed location_

Comment: Possibly your school is at North Pole :) ROFLMFAO

Comment: @TilakMaddy its actually of the coast of Africa (0,0 i mean, not my school haha)

Answer (score 0):

According to [docs](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp) `navigator.geolocation` is not going to be supported in **Chrome** with `http://` (**v50.0+**). Use `https://` instead if that's possible.

That can also cause your issue because you mentioned that only in some places and I guess in some (chrome) browsers it doesn't work.

> **Note:** As of Chrome 50, the Geolocation API will only work on secure
>   contexts such as HTTPS. If your site is hosted on an non-secure origin
>   (such as HTTP) the requests to get the users location will no longer
>   function.